# User groups is null after edit user joomla 3

Tags: joomla-3.x, upgrade, user-groups

I have upgraded my Joomla 2.5 to Joomla 3. After edit user, user groups will be empty.

```
$user = JFactory::getUser();
$groups = $user->groups();
```

Is there anyone who faced same problem?

I checked by removing overridden files and plugings also. But no luck yet.

=========Update===============
User object

```
JUser Object
(
    [isRoot:protected] => 
    [id] => 442
    [name] => test user
    [username] => testr
    [email] => testr@abc.com
    [password] => hash_code here
    [password_clear] => 
    [block] => 0
    [sendEmail] => 0
    [registerDate] => 2014-02-27 05:26:39
    [lastvisitDate] => 2015-02-24 08:06:47
    [activation] => 
    [params] => {"admin_style":"","admin_language":"","language":"","editor":"","helpsite":"","timezone":""}
    [groups] => 
    [guest] => 0
    [lastResetTime] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
    [resetCount] => 0
    [requireReset] => 0
    [_params:protected] => Joomla\Registry\Registry Object
        (
            [data:protected] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [admin_style] => 
                    [admin_language] => 
                    [language] => 
                    [editor] => 
                    [helpsite] => 
                    [timezone] => 
                )

        )
```

I found following same issue but no answers yet - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26635378/user-groups-is-null-after-editing-user-and-saving

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I have just checked save method in profile model. There is line as follows. line no 362-363.

```
    // Null the user groups so they don't get overwritten
$user->groups = null;
```

I commented out that line. It works fine. I don't know which area will affect after commenting out that line.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue which took me quite a long time to realise what had gone wrong. I'm not too sure what had happened but wrote an answer a while back to sort the problem out:

[You cannot access the private section of this site](https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/you-cannot-access-the-private-section-of-this-site)

Hope this helps

Comment: I have added answer but I don't know it is correct answer for that. Can you have a look at it?