# Unable to access the admin section of my new joomla 3x site in localhost

Tags: login

I have trouble with my new Joomla 3.x site (installed in localhost (WAMP 2.4) the day before) , my OS is windows XP Professional ,laptop DELL Inspiron 640m.
 I can't access neither the backend nor the frontend of my site, this is the error message i got

```
Error You cannot access the private section of this site
```

I thought it was a password issue so I changed my password (in users table with MD5 function) but no positive result.
Any advise.
Nadir.

Comment: Please note that Joomla 3.x does not use MD5 for hashing passwords. It uses Bcrypt. I also had the same issue a while back and wrote a solution: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/you-cannot-access-the-private-section-of-this-site

Comment: When do you get that error, and what do you mean by "can't access".  Does the admin login come up when you browse to the administrator section?  Are you trying to login with Super Admin or another user?  Did it ever work right after installation?

Comment: @Lodder  I don't know about Bcrypt , I followed the steps of a video which was using MD5 to hash passwords . i checked to find Bcrypt , i didn't find it in functions.

Comment: @Lodder  When I pasted your code : [link](http://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/4174/you-cannot-access-the-private-section-of-this-site) in localhost and executed it , I have got an error message : ' #1146 - Table 'joomla.jos_user_usergroup_map' doesn't exist'

Comment: @Lance  I got the error when I installed joomla 3.0.1 , i was trying to login as admin  from backend .<br/> now I can't got the backend page I have only the frontend one and when i try to access the site admin I have the error message again .

Comment: @Nadir - `jos_` is the table prefix that applied to me. You need to change this to what ever **your** table prefix is

Comment: @Lodder I followed your explanation , I have pasted the code :<br/>         INSERT INTO `jos_user_usergroup_map` (`user_id`, `group_id`) SELECT `id`, '2' FROM `jos_users` WHERE `id` NOT IN (SELECT `user_id` FROM `jos_user_usergroup_map`);  with my table's prefix , now I can login in frontend (** I can see "hi Super User" in the login form** ) but when i try to login from backend it returns the same error message of before   **You cannot access the private section of this site**

Comment: Try opening the `jos_user_usergroup_map` table in the database, search for your user ID and make sure the group ID assigned is `8`. To be honest, you could simply try re-installing a fresh copy of Joomla again

Comment: @Lodder I did what you suggest me to do , I found that '8' is attributed to Super Users

Comment: But is `8` assigned to **your** user ID?

Comment: Have I  to delete all joomla folders and reinstall a new one ,                      Is there another method to install joomla on the first one .

Comment: @Lodder no,  1 is assigned to my user ID

Comment: Please change `1` to `8`. You should hopefully be allowed to access the admin panel after

Comment: I changed 1 to 8 , no chance , can't access

Comment: Thank you Lodder  and all guys for helping me .    <br/>   
 
Have I to delete all joomla folders and reinstall a new one , Is there another method to install joomla on the first one

Answer (score 1):

The error message in Joomla when the username/password don't match are: Warning | Username and password do not match or you do not have an account yet.

Your error seems to be related to the frontend, and the corresponding administrator section error would be:

```
You do not have access to the Administrator section of this site.
```

This is all caused during the "authorization" process after you login.  Basically "authentication" completes successfully (in other words your username and password are correct) then the code looks to see what you're allowed, or authorized, to access.

The error is triggered here:

```
File: plugins/user/joomla/joomla.php
Function: onUserLogin
Line: (approx 198-207)
      // Check the user can login.
      $result = $instance->authorise($options['action']);

      if (!$result)
      {
           $this->app->enqueueMessage(JText::_('JERROR_LOGIN_DENIED'), 'warning');
           return false;
      }
```

What you need to do is either reinstall your site, or look up issues with the ACL tables.  I would recommend reinstalling.

Comment: Ok Lance I will reinstall Joomla , thank you and to all guys for your help